# Trying to create two CSV files from parsed text code in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to code. I am trying to amend a program I found online to filter out only those lines with the ICD10 of M32 or some variation (M32.1, M32.2 etc).

When I run the code, I get a lot of repetitive outputs into my table and I'm not sure why or how to fix it, can you help me?

```
fileObj = open(r"C:\Users\RSHAR\Documents\Research Project\CDC Data Download\CDC Data Download\Eric Yen _9-17-2020\MortAC1999\MULT1999.AllCnty\MULT1999.AllCnty.txt",'r')
fileOutObj = open(r"C:\Users\RSHAR\Documents\Research Project\CDC Data Download\CDC Data Download\Eric Yen _9-17-2020\MortAC1999\MULT1999.AllCnty\MULT1999.AllCnty.M32.csv","a")
fileOutObj.write('Record, Sex, Race_R1, Race_R2, Hispanic_Origin_Recode, Age, Marital, Education, ICD10, FIPS_Occur_State, FIPS_Occur_County, FIPS_Reside_State, FIPS_Reside_County, FIPS_Reside_City, Record_Axis\n')

outStr = ""

for line in fileObj:
        Record = line[18].strip()
        Sex = line[58].strip()
        Race_R1 = line[61].strip()
        Race_R2 = line[62].strip()
        Hispanic_Origin_Recode = line[81].strip()
        Age = line[63:65].strip()
        Marital = line[76].strip()
        Education = line[51:52].strip()
        ICD10 = line[141:144].strip()
        FIPS_Occur_State = line[118:119].strip()
        FIPS_Occur_County = line[120:122].strip()
        FIPS_Reside_State = line[123:124].strip()
        FIPS_Reside_County = line[125:127].strip()
        FIPS_Reside_City = line[96:100].strip()
        Record_Axis = line [340:439].strip()
        if ICD10 in ['M32']:
            outStr = (Record+ ','+Sex+ ',' +Race_R1 +              ', ' + Race_R2+ ', ' + Hispanic_Origin_Recode +', '+ Age +               ', ' + Marital +         ', ' + Education + \
                         ', ' + ICD10 +               ', ' + FIPS_Occur_State +              ', ' + FIPS_Occur_County +           ', ' + FIPS_Reside_State + \
                         ', ' + FIPS_Reside_County + ', ' +FIPS_Reside_City +', ' + Record_Axis + '\n')
        fileOutObj.write(outStr)



print("Parse complete.")
fileOutObj.close()
fileObj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object outStr should be reseted to an empty string after each iteration. Otherwise each new line is added to the old one. When writing to file the complete string is written again. You could define the outstring inside the loop so that the scope is defined as the one iteration of the loop.

Inside the `if`-statement there is something wired. The variable ICD10 is a string of the form M32.*. You are comparing this string to elements of the array defined in this line. There is only the element 'M32'.

I propose some different solution, which removes the for loop. I let do it by pandas.

There is the function `read_fwf` of pandas. You can define your columns and give them the names. After reading, you can filter for the column ICD10.

```
tbl = pd.read_fwf("data_file.txt",
  colspecs=[[0,1], [2, 3], [3, 8]],
  header=None,
  names=["Record ", "ICD10"]
  usecols=[1])
```

After reading you can write it to disc with `to_csv`

If your file is too big to read at once try the argument `chunksize` or `iterator`. Only in case that was the reason, that you defined your own loop.